# Categorise string based on keyword

Tags: javascript

I have a string that can be anything.

I have a bunch of different functions which will be called dependent on the keywords in the string. Only the first matched keyword will be applicable, so no need for a use case of multiple matches.

Let's say I have this logic
- if string includes 'curtains', call someCurtainFunction()
- if string includes 'cheese', call someCheeseFunction()

Right now I am doing this:

```
if(someString.includes('curtains')){
    someCurtainFunction(params);
} else if(someString.includes('cheese')){
    someCheeseFunction(params);
}
```

And that's fine - it works. But the list is quite long. It isn't the most readable.

So I thought about something like this, but it seems a bit bad practise to use `eval()`

```
var keywords = {
    'curtains': 'someCurtainFunction(params)',
    'cheese': 'someCheeseFunction(params)'
}

for(var keyword of Object.keys(keywords)){
  if(someString.includes(keyword)){
    eval(keywords[keyword]);
    break;
  }
}
```

How best would I tackle this issue without eval?

Comment: SO just reference the function

Comment: @epascarello they need to be able to pass in parameters

Comment: So than add an object with additional parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if `params` change:

```
var keywords = {
    'curtains': ()=>someCurtainFunction(params),
    'cheese': ()=>someCheeseFunction(params)
}
for (let keyword of Object.keys(keywords)){
    if(someString.includes(keyword)){
      keywords[keyword]();
      break;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if all the functions are called with the same `params`, just store a reference to the functions:

```
var keywords = {
    'curtains': someCurtainFunction,
    'cheese': someCheeseFunction
}
for (let keyword of Object.keys(keywords)){
    if(someString.includes(keyword)){
      keywords[keyword](params);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes params will change. Thanks that's a novel approach.